# Need to remove hyphen in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array with some elements in it.

```
var arr=["bet-vet","ban-van","baskat-vase"];
```

While displaying the array, the want the hyphen in between the words to be removed. When it is being displayed,
the user should see

```
Bet,vet,ban,van,baskat,vase
```

[Here is the link of my code](http://jsbin.com/quxipajupe/edit?js,output)

Comment: One option: `arr.map(function(el) { return el.split('-'); }).join()`

Comment: Should be showing what you tried. This site is intended to help you with your code...not write it from scratch for you. There are lots and lots of other posts you could have gotten at least a start point from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript `Joint() & Split() method`

example:

```js
var arr=["bet-vet","ban-van","baskat-vase"];
var arrJoin = arr.join("-");
var arrsplit = arrJoin.split("-");
console.log(arrsplit);
```

Answer (score 3):

You ca try:

```js
var arr = ["bet-vet", "ban-van", "baskat-vase"];

arr= arr.join("-").split("-").join();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script>
var b_or_v =["bet-vet","bat-vat","reb-rev","bick-vic","ban-van"];

function removeHyphen()
{
    var newArray = [];
    for(i=0;i<b_or_v.length;i++)
    {
        res = b_or_v[i].split("-");
        newArray.push(res[0]);
        newArray.push(res[1]);
    }
    console.log(newArray);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = newArray;
}
</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="removeHyphen()">Find Val</button>
    <div id="text">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lajm0qg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code as mentioned below:

```
document.getElementById("btn-1").onclick= function(){
document.getElementById("submit").onclick= function(){
  var txt = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < b_or_v.length; i++) { 
    if(b_or_v[i].match(/-/g)){
      txt += b_or_v[i].split('-');
      txt += ', ';
    }
    else{
      txt += b_or_v[i]+', ';

    }
}
```

Output: b_or_v : bet, vet, bat, vat, reb, rev, bick, vic, ban, van,

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
var arr = ["bet-vet", "ban-van", "baskat-vase"];
var arr1 = [];
for(var i= 0; i < arr.length;i++){
  test= arr[i].replace('-', '');
  arr1.push(test);
}
console.log(arr1.join(', '));
```